# Use of “would” in the specific situation

Tags: modal-verbs

> A man asked a question to his friend, “Why was it the best time for
> Bilal to be in his home?”
>
> His friend replied, “It **would** be the best
> time for Bilal to be in his home because his uncle visited him at that time.”

In what sense is the modal verb *would* being used above?

Can we replace the *would* used there with this instead:

> It might have been the best time. . . ..

What job does *would* do in the quoted dialogue above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The phrase *in his home* is not the usual idiom: we normally say *at home*. This doesn't necessarily mean that the phrase is wrong or unidiomatic; it’s possible to imagine circumstances in which *in his home* would be exactly the right way to put it; but it raises the suspicion that the speakers were not native speakers.
2. The answer is not unambiguously responsive to the question: ordinarily an answer is expressed with the same tense and mood as the question. Here, however, the question is expressed using the simple past, but the answer uses a construction with *would*; and although  *would* is indeed the simple past form of *will*, its use implies one of these meanings:

   - a ‘future-in-the-past’—that is, something which happened **after** *his uncle visited*; but that is very far-fetched, and really requires elaboration: “It would *turn out to be* the best time because *it just so happened that* his uncle visited him at that time” ...
   - a ‘hypothetical’—something which would be true **if** something else were true;  but there’s  no *if* clause here ...
   - an offhand and somewhat dismissive assertion, more or less equivalent to *has to* or *must*—“Oh, it has to be because his uncle visited him at that time.”

   So there are two possible misuses, and one possible correct use. You may be charitable and assume that the speaker was using *would* correctly. Me, given point 1, I doubt it: I just don't think a native speaker would construct so formal a sentence as that with *would* in that sense.

I think you are probably right in your guess that what the speaker meant was *might have been*; but that's not something which the construction with *would* expresses.

Comment: So 'might have been' doesn't mean the same thing? The sentence is not by a native speaker, and I know that he meant 'might have been'. I just want to confirm whether 'would' is interchangeable with 'might have been', in the sense that is expressed by 'might have been'?

Comment: @SamamaFahim *Would* is **not** interchangeable with *might have been*. Nohow, no way. :)

Comment: @SamamaFahim  However, it **would** be possible to substitute *could be* (or *could have been*, either will work) for *might have been* in this context.

Comment: But I learnt from the British Council that 'might be, may be, and could be' or these modal verbs without 'be' are used to say how much sure we're about something in the present about a future event. Example: Don’t put it up there. It could fall off and hit someone.

Comment: @SamamaFahim  Quite right. They are also used to express uncertainty about present events: "For all I know he could be there now." I put *be* in because that's the verb in  your example: "It could be the best time because ... ". There's a lot of overlap between *may/might* and *can/could*; and in fact over the last couple of centuries *can* has been gradually replacing *may* in many contexts. That's not a 'rule', though, just a tendency.

Comment: I think any language didn't ever have any particular set of rules. Not even in my native language, there are particular sets of rules.

Comment: Let's say, I make a prediction "He will have gone to China last year." Can I backshift it to "he would have gone to China last year."? @StoneyB

Comment: @Zhanlong You can't predict something that happens in the past. "He will have gone to China last year" is not a prediction but an inference: "I infer that he went to China last year."

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of words. It is indeed an inference. So how to backshift it? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng "She said (then) that he would have gone to China the year before." But you'll need more context to distinguish this from a counterfactual.

Comment: Thx! Btw, back to my ELL post, Can the “would have + past participle” construction be used to express an assumption or expectation about a past event as these two grammar books indicate? Please, I can't sleep for that! Yes or no? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Well, I'd call it an *inference* rather than an *assumption* or *expectation*, but yeah.

Comment: OK, the last one: e.g. We can't go and see them now - they will have gone to bed. If I said **"they would have gone to bed."** instead, would it be a softer, less certain version of "they will have gone to bed."? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Very unlikely.  With *have*, *would* is almost always past: it's either a backshifted *will have* or a past irrealis *would*. To express what you want we'd **qualify** *will* than cast it in the remote *would*: "I think they'll have gone to bed" or "they'll have probably gone to bed" or something of that sort.

Comment: Thx, I think you omitted a "rather" before "than" in your words. Right?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Yes, quite so.

Comment: You mentioned "would" could mean "an offhand and somewhat dismissive assertion". Is this **the** inferential usage of "would"? That is to say, when "would" is used this way, it always goes with such a tone?  @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Not at all; I say that because that's how I as an actor would understand the substitution of *would* for *must* **in this particular conversation**.

Comment: OK. The last one: you say that it **would** be possible to substitute _could be_ (or _could have been_, either will work) for _might have been_ in this context. If "could have been" was used, it would be equivalent to _might have been._ If "could be" was used, it would be equivalent to the backshifted version of _can be._ But it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng: It's more complicated than that. We don't use positive *can* for present possibility or inference, but *could*: "It could be that..." = "It is possible that" OR "I infer that...". We use *can* for present possibility/inference only in the negative: "It cannot be that...". Backshifted *cannot* becomes *could not*; but  possible/inferential *could* does not change form when it is backshifted: "He said that it could be that..." = "He said that it was possible that ...". Present *could* is backshifted to *could have been* only when it represents an irrealis.

Comment: In retrospect, I realize I didn't fully understand your answer and comments at the time. That's why I asked a few dumb recurring questions. "Ordinarily an answer is expressed with the same tense and mood as the question" is the key to my ELL's questions. "It would be the best time for Bilal to be" in fact is backshifted version of "It will be the best time..". It's "will" rather than "would" that signifies the assumption, the same as in that 'helicopter' example. If the context was stated in the present tense, using "would have done.." for inference would be a poor choice. Am I right? @StoneyB